# The ideal structure of the Haagerup tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, tensor-products

I'm currently reading the paper [The ideal structure of the Haagerup tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras](https://eudml.org/doc/153553) and having difficulty in understanding the proof of Proposition $4.5$ from the paper.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras and $I$ be a nonzero closed ideal of $A \otimes^{\text{min}} B$,  then $I$ contains a nonzero elementary tensor.

Suppose not. Let $\pi: A \otimes^{\text{min}} B \to \frac{A \otimes^{\text{min}} B}{I}$ be the natural map, and define a $C^{\ast}$-seminorm as $N(u) = \| \pi(u) \|$ for $ u \in A \otimes^{\text{min}} B$. By assumption, $N(a\otimes b) > 0$ for all nonzero elementary tensors $a \otimes b$.

Then it's written that $N$ norm dominates the min norm, but I don't understand how $N$ is a norm. I can only see that it's a seminorm.

P.S: This question was first posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702288/difficulty-in-understanding-a-proof-from-an-article).

Comment: If one of the two $C^*$-algebras is exact, this is true. See corollary 9.4.6 in the book "C*-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations" by Brown-Ozawa.

Comment: An important part of their argument missing from your post is the reference to Takesaki's paper.  Did you miss the reference or do you not understand how the claim follows form Takesaki's paper?

Comment: Dear @CalebEckhardt: I don't understand how it follows from Takesaki's paper. Can you please elaborate? Regards,